# Binary transformation

Tags: binary, binary-operations

The best way to explain this is with examples.

Insert a 0 at end: Multiply by 2

`1010` -> (*2) -> `10100`

Insert a 1 at end: Multiply by 2 and add 1

`1010` -> (*2+1) -> `10101`

Insert a 0 at start: Do nothing

`1010` -> (*1) -> `1010` == `01010`

What is the solution for insert a 1 at start?

Note: Add 2^4 is not a valid answer as it only works with 4 bits while the other 3 methods work on all bit lengths. Use big endian.

Edit: Just to make it double clear. The answer needs to be static like the other 3 methods. Checking the number of digits it has and then adding 2^n is NOT a valid answer. Assume we cannot count the number of digits.

Comment: Step 1: find out how many digits there are in the binary representation (use logarithms and cieling or floor functions).  Step 2: find out the value that corresponds to $100\dots 0$ in binary where there are as many $0$'s as there are digits of the number you want to prepend the $1$ to.

Comment: @JMoravitz Updated the question to emphasize that adding 2^n is not a valid answer. It works, but it's not what I'm looking for. Assume I can't check the number of digits.

Comment: You can always check the number of digits.  It is, as I alluded to earlier, merely checking the logarithm base 2 of the number you are modifying.  If the number you are modifying is $x$ then $x$ is $\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor + 1$ digits long in binary.  The result of your modification is then $x + 2^{\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor + 2}$.  If you want to say that the formula cannot involve $x$ in any way, then it is impossible, but then so too is the formula for inserting a zero at the end since that formula involves $x$ as well as it is $2x$

Comment: If you can't check the number of digits you can't even know what the previous number is, so I think you are transforming a normal question in a non-sense one.

Comment: @JMoravitz You can't use logarithms on elliptic curves and I can do 2x on elliptic curves without knowing x.

Comment: Ignoring the truth of that statement, what does that have to do with anything?  And why should that matter.  Why do you even require a different way of representing the function "prepend a 1" when using words is perfectly clear in the first place and is a perfectly valid function.

Comment: @JMoravitz As I've already said, that answer is not what I'm looking for. I mentioned since the very beggining + 2^n wouldn't solve the problem. If you don't have a valid answer please stop trying to make your answer valid and let others reply. That solution doesn't solve the problem I need to solve on elliptic curves.

Answer (score 1):

If your starting binary number has $n$ digits, adding 1 at the start means "add $2^n$ to the starting number"

Comment: This is essentialy add 2^4 which is not a valid answer as outlined on the question note section. It works, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: there is not another answer, this is what happens. If you add a "1" at the start of a number in any base $\beta$ you are adding $\beta^n$ to the starting number, where n is the length of the starting number.